# How to make a number os points decrease according to the user

Tags: c#, logic

Right now i have something like this:

```
int numero = 27;
while (numero >= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escolha o status de sua classe:  ");
    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("inteligencia: ");
    int inteligencia = Convert.ToInt32(value: Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - inteligencia;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("Força: ");
    int forca = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - forca;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("Fe: ");
    int fe = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - fe;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("vitalidade: ");
    int vitalidade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - vitalidade;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("Energia: ");
    int energia = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - energia;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("Magia: ");
    int magia = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - magia;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("Defesa: ");
    int defesa = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - defesa;

    Console.WriteLine("Você tem : " + numero + " de pontos para gastar");
    Console.Write("Vigor: ");
    int vigor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    numero = numero - vigor;
}
```

the thing is, i want it to stop as soon the number reaches 0,the  but i dont want any of the other atributes to have no value inputed(they could receive 0 as a value)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why do you want your `int` variables (inteligencia, forca,... etc) to have a value after `numero` reaches 0. These variables are not being used after the loop is exited and they are not saved anywhere. I'm guessing you want to use them later in the loop.

But still you need to stop changing `numero` when `numero` is 0 or less and finish the loop normally. First, I would really suggest you to extract a method like so:

```
public int GetUserValue(string valuePrompt)
{
    Console.Write(valuePrompt);
    return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

and use it like this:

```
int inteligencia = GetUserValue($"Você tem : {numero} de pontos para gastar\ninteligencia: ")
```

(read about string interpolation here (the `$` sign):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

and about `\n` and other character escapes here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions)

Second the easiest way to stop changing `numero` is to add a condition to check if it's greater than 0 before you make the change. Let's move this change logic in a separate method as well:

```
public int GetReducedNumero(int numero, int userValue)
{
    return numero > 0? numero - userValue : numero;
}
```

This way, `numero` won't change if it's already 0 or less.
And finally let me show you, how this all should look in the end:

```
public void YourMainMethod()
{
    //...

    int numero = 27;

    //if you want to stop when numero reaches 0, you should use > instead of >=
    while (numero > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escolha o status de sua classe:  ");

        int inteligencia = GetUserValue($"Você tem : {numero} de pontos para gastar\ninteligencia: ")
        numero = GetReducedNumero(numero, inteligencia);

        int forca = GetUserValue($"Você tem : {numero} de pontos para gastar\nForça: ")
        numero = GetReducedNumero(numero, forca );

        //and so on..
    }
}

public int GetUserValue(string valuePrompt)
{
    Console.Write(valuePrompt);
    return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

public int GetReducedNumero(int numero, int userValue)
{
    return numero > 0? numero - userValue : numero;
}
```

Hope that helps!